# getSupportActionBar from inside of Fragment ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I'm starting a new project that uses the `AppCompat/ActionBarCompat` in `v7` support library. I'm trying to figure out how to use the `getSupportActionBar` from within a fragment. My activity that hosts the fragment extends `ActionBarActivity`, but I don't see a similar support class for Fragments.

From within my fragment

```
    public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
          //...

          getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle); // getSupportActionBar is not defined in the v4 version of Fragment

          //...
    }
```

The google page for using it (http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) says there should be no changes for the `v4` fragment. Do I need to cast all my `getActivity()` calls to an `ActionBarActivity`? That seems like poor design.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

After **Fragment.onActivityCreated(...)** you'll have a valid activity accessible through getActivity().

You'll need to cast it to an ActionBarActivity then make the call to getSupportActionBar().

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
```

You do need the cast. It's not poor design, it's backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this would not be the answer. I was hoping maybe that getActionBar() would return a v7 ActionBar that I would cast to if I needed the extra functionality. Now my Fragments have to be aware of what type of Activity they are hosted in.

Comment: No it doesn't because getActionBar() is an Activity API that does not exist on older versions of the SDK (pre-honeycomb). This is why we need support classes that mirror the functionality of the new and improved classes and APIs in more recent SDKs.

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineLaFayette Why does this have to be done in onAttach()?  Wouldn't it be better in onActivityCreated()?

Comment: Yes since the first call to getSupportActionBar() will initialize the ActionBar by looking up the views in the activity, it is probably better for this call to be done in onActivityCreated(). I was more just trying to indicate that you need to wait till the fragment has an activity. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Casting 'getActivity()' to 'ActionBarActivity' is redundant. Something we can do about it?

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity

Comment: Here is the same implementation translated into Kotlin:

(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar.setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle)

Answer (score 38):

While this question has an accepted answer already, I must point out that it isn't totally correct: calling `getSupportActionBar()` from `Fragment.onAttach()` will cause a `NullPointerException` when the activity is rotated.

**Short answer:**

Use `((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()` in **`onActivityCreated()`** (or any point afterwards in its lifecycle) instead of `onAttach()`.

**Long answer:**

The reason is that if an `ActionBarActivity` is recreated after a rotation, it will restore all Fragments *before* actually creating the `ActionBar` object.

Source code for `ActionBarActivity` in the `support-v7` library:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mImpl = ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mImpl.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

- `ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate()` creates the `mImpl` object depending on the Android version.
- `super.onCreate()` is `FragmentActivity.onCreate()`, which restores any previous fragments after a rotation (`FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate()`, &c).
- `mImpl.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is `ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate()`, which reads the `mHasActionBar` variable from the window style.
- Before `mHasActionBar` is true, `getSupportActionBar()` will always return `null`.

Source for `ActionBarActivityDelegate.getSupportActionBar()`:

```
final ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    // The Action Bar should be lazily created as mHasActionBar or mOverlayActionBar
    // could change after onCreate
    if (mHasActionBar || mOverlayActionBar) {
        if (mActionBar == null) {
            ... creates the action bar ...
        }
    } else {
        // If we're not set to have a Action Bar, null it just in case it's been set
        mActionBar = null;
    }
    return mActionBar;
}
```

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Use `AppCompatActivity` instead

Comment: `onActivityCreated` is now also deprecated (see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02 for alternatives).

Answer (score 30):

If someone uses com.android.support:appcompat-v7: and AppCompatActivity  as activity then this will work

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
```

Answer (score 7):

For those using kotlin,

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar.setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle)
```

Answer (score 6):

As an updated answer for Pierre-Antoine LaFayette's answer

ActionBarActivity is deprecated; use `AppCompatActivity` instead

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 5):

in your `fragment.xml` add `Toolbar` Tag from support library

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Now how we can control it from `MyFragment` class? let's see

inside `onCreateView` function add the following

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

//add this line if you want to provide Up Navigation but don't forget to to 
//identify parent activity in manifest file
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and if you want to add `items` to the toolbar within `MyFragment` 
you `must` add this line inside `onCreateView` function

```
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

this line is important, if you forget it, android will not populate your menu Items.

assume we identify them in `menu/fragment_menu.xml`

after that override the following functions

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_1:
            // do stuff
            return true;

        case R.id.action_2:
            // do more stuff
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to GzDev's answer, if you already have the string, you can use kotlin's auto-setter:

`(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.subtitle = my_string`

And you can turn it off by simply using an empty string.

Note that this works for both the *title* and the *subtitle*.