# NullPointerException when calling getSupportActionBar() from inside of Fragment (ActionBarCompat)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I just switched from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat and everything was working well until I ran into this small error. I have a base activity that extends `ActionBarActivity` and has 3 fragments associated with it. In one of the Fragments `onAttach` method, I try executing this code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    final ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle("");
}
```

It works fine until I try to change my screen orientation. Then I get a `NullPointerException` for this line of code: `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is the entire error log:

```
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586): Process: com.packagename.appname, PID: 18586
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packagename.appname/com.packagename.appname.activities.NewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:169)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at com.packagename.appname.fragments.NewFragment.onAttach(NewFragment.java:144)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:883)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1879)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:215)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:97)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at com.packagename.appname.activities.NewActivity.onCreate(NewActivity.java:73)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
06-10 18:53:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(18586):    ... 12 more
```

FYI: `NewFragment` line 144 is: `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled`.

Comment: post the error not just part of it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin just added it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onAttach()` may be far too soon. When the activity is recreated after a rotation, it is one of the first methods called, even before the Activity is fully created (i.e. its `onCreate()` hasn't finished yet). So it's not surprising that the `ActionBar` isn't ready.

Check the [relationship between Activity and Fragment's lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CoordinatingWithActivity) in the documentation.

In short: move this code into `onActivityCreated()` or `onStart()`.

**Further explanation**

Check the source code for `ActionBarActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mImpl = ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mImpl.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

- `super.onCreate()` is `FragmentActivity.onCreate()`, which restores any previous fragments after a rotation.
- `mImpl.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is `ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate()`, which reads the `mHasActionBar` variable from the window style.
- Before `mHasActionBar` is true, `getSupportActionBar()` will always return null.

Comment: That's not what [this post said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320713/getsupportactionbar-from-inside-of-fragment-actionbarcompat?rq=1)...

Comment: @lschessinger It will work on the _first_ `onAttach()`. But not after a rotation. At least with the current version of the support library.

Comment: This worked for me. The only change would be to replace `activity` with `getActivity()`. Thanks!

Comment: @lschessinger I'm glad it worked. I added an answer to the other question to point it out (from the upvotes it seems that many people read it). :/

Comment: `onActivityCreated` is now deprecated (see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02 for alternatives).