# How to hide the actionbar in some activities

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an application, when I test it in 2.3.3 the activities I want don't have an actionbar, but when I test it in emulator using 4.2, those activities have an action bar.

How can I remove the actionbar completely from those activities.

I tried this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545370/android-how-to-hide-actionbar-on-certain-activities):
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Doesn't work.

If I use getActionBar().hide(), and test it on my 2.3.3 it crashes. And if I try getSupportActionBar().hide() i get error: The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined. Note: I am not extending actionbar activity. I am extending Activity.

Comment: Depending on the min API you are using, you can try to use `getActionBar().hide()` or `getSupportActionBar().hide()` in the `onCreate()` method of the activities you want to display without action bar.

Comment: If I use `getActionBar().hide()`, and test it on my 2.3.3 it crashes. And if I try `getSupportActionBar().hide()` i get error: `The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined`. Note: I am not extending actionbar activity. I am extending Activity.

Comment: Can't you extend ActionBarActivity?

Comment: EDIT: Let me try extending

Comment: @G.T. that fixed it. What about extending FragmentActivity? I'm using some calendar library, and it extends FragmentActivity. How can I disable the actionbar in this activity?

Comment: You have to cast the fragment to an ActionBarActivity, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/18320838/3571822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From the comments I wrote)*

First, make your classes extends `ActionBarActivity`. Then call this method in the `onCreate()` callback of the activies in which you want to hide the action bar:

```
private void hideActionBar() {
    //Hide the action bar only if it exists
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the action bar with the `getActionBar().hide()` method (Or `getSupportActionBar().hide` is you are using support library.

or

You can call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in `onCreate` method before calling `setContentView`.