# Android ActionBar missing after extending Appcompatactivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, hockeyapp

I've recently updated my app extending `Appcompatactivity` in my `Activities`. Since then, the `Actionbar` is gone  when I launch an external library Intent.

For example, I'm using the `HockeyApp` SDK to launch their `FeedbackActivity`

Here is my code:

```
FeedbackManager.showFeedbackActivity(this, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

And here a screenshot (you can see the `ActionBar` is gone).

[image]

It used to work before until I started extending Appcompatactivity.

For the rest of `Activities` it works. The `ActionBar is gone` only when I launch an external library `Intent`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First, check your theme it may be like below ("NoActionBar"). Then the action bar is not appearing. If this is your issue. please add an appropriate theme for your application

```
 <application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    />
```

if your theme is not a problem, you can add below content to your XML file. (add this as a first child of your XML file)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

and add below content to your activity on create method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .......
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}
```

Comment: @Ale what is the error now? same or different. Please make sure that u add Toolbar as a first child of xml

Comment: your solution is correct but it doesn't work in out context because we are launching an external Intent. When we launch `FeedbackManager.showFeedbackActivity(this, Uri.fromFile(file));` it opens a new `Activity` (from the HockeyApp SDK) but we cannot modify its layout.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably that `FeedbackManager.showFeedbackActivity(this, Uri.fromFile(file))` opens a new FeedbackActivity.class which is subclass of Activity.class instead of AppCompatActivity.class, so it can not show the ActionBar.Here is a link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681918/nullpointerexception-with-actionbar-setdisplayhomeasupenabledboolean-on-a-nu` that explains some reasons.