# Add toolbar in constraintLayout of a fragment layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to add a toolbar inside a constraint layout but this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't fit the whole screen. 
Here's my xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment title"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The ConstraintLayout width and length are set to match parent (which should be the screen?) and the toolbar width is set to match the layout width.
What am I missing?

Comment: check answer of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086154/android-actionbar-missing-after-extending-appcompatactivity/53086384#53086384

Comment: try to add custom toolbar ?

Comment: toolbar autometically added in fragment if you are added custom view then create custom view file

Comment: this is activity xml or fragment xml ?

Comment: This is the layout of a fragment

Comment: I think you've provided with the main_activity.xml .. please see the layout file and also post you fragment java file code

Answer (score 1):

Try this out by adding these content inside toolbar

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```

I got this from [Android: remove left margin from actionbar's custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout). And u can try other solutions in there as well if this is not solve your problem.

Comment: This didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

try this you have to set the constraintTop to the parent and also make width value match constraints and set start and end constraint to parent,

check the code below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This didn't help. Nothing changed.

Comment: so if use fragment check if the frame layout  or fragment view doesn't have any padding or margin on your activity XML

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by putting the action bar on the main activity instead of the fragment layout.