# Need help figuring out why App keeps stopping when I click "Settings" Button

Tags: android, settings, toolbar, android-monitor

I receive the following error in Android Studio "Android Monitor"

There's a lot of mumbo-jumbo but it's essentially saying the cause of the error is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual  method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a  null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.robthoms.photopop.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:28)
```

I'm trying to make Settings work on the Toolbar and I got the code from:

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/

If you click on this link you'll see the entire code for SettingsActivity.java that I'm trying to use but when I click on "settings" in toolbar, App closes.

What is wrong with SettingsActivity that the app closes?

My AndroidManifest.xml:

[image]

My styles.xml

[image]

Hides ActionBar in classes while styles.xml has Light.DarkActionBar

```
    ActionBar bar  = getSupportActionBar () ;
    if       (bar != null) bar.hide () ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144657/android-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-app-actionbar-on

Comment: Could you post your SettingsActivity.java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because your activity do not have any ActionBar. In android manifest, make sure your activity is using the theme which has an `ActionBar`. Make sure it doesn't have something like `NoActionBar`. If your activity is not using any theme, check your `AppTheme` in `styles.xml`.

One possible solution would be to use this in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Another way:**

Add new style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

And use new style in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: I edited above and included my AndroidManifest.xml and Styles.xml, so what am I missing? What is wrong?

Comment: In your styles.xml use Theme.AppCompat.Light instead of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: if  I enable action bar in styles.xml then it'll show me an action bar across all XML files. I don't want to see action bars on any XML files but I still need the settings to work. Is there a work around? Can I make the action bar include in only specific XML files instead of all?

Comment: You can use `Toolbar`: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: Rabin thank you but adding in this code to manifest just crashes my app again.

Comment: @iBEK what is the new problem?

Comment: @iBEK post your new manifest, new styles.xml and new stacktrace of crash.

Comment: Now I got the settings to work but the action bar now appears on All XML files. Is there a way to hide action bar from other XML files?

Comment: In manifest, use AppTheme for activities which don't need action bar, and use AppTheme.ActionBar ro activitiew which need action bar.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out and got it working with the action bar hidden in other XML files. I used the above code in various Java classes to hide action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Your style theme is noactionbar
1. If you want an actionbar use actionbar containing theme
OR
2. You can also make custom view similar to actionbar