# Why does my android application keep stopping?

Tags: java, android

This application only has front end work. I worked really hard on it but on running it keeps stopping.
Here is the stacktrace

```
2021-05-26 07:13:37.288 3836-3836/? I/le.instagramap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-05-26 07:13:37.337 3836-3836/? E/le.instagramap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-05-26 07:13:37.384 3836-3836/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
2021-05-26 07:13:37.384 3836-3836/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
2021-05-26 07:13:37.859 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2021-05-26 07:13:38.427 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp D/PhoneWindow: forceLight changed to true [] from com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.updateForceLightNavigationBar:4238 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews:1510 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged:3216 android.view.Window.setFlags:1148 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout:2444 
2021-05-26 07:13:38.429 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@3d08565[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2021-05-26 07:13:38.429 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@3d08565[]
2021-05-26 07:13:38.449 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp W/le.instagramap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-26 07:13:38.450 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp W/le.instagramap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-26 07:13:38.465 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-05-26 07:13:38.468 3836-3836/com.example.instagramapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.instagramapp, PID: 3836
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.instagramapp/com.example.instagramapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:103)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:233)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:227)
        at com.example.instagramapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3531)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Kindly help me resolve the issue. I have recently started android development so sorry if this question does not pass the site's standards.

Comment: Your  reference to Actionbar is null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Tell us how did you declare and initialize your `actionbar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling getSupportActionBar().

Here is a reference article:

[Android Error [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar' on a null object reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144657/android-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-app-actionbar-on)

I've also recently got into Android development and as a heads up, if your emulator starts to have issues, make sure you wipe its data. Go to AKD manager, click the arrow to the far right, and select wipe data.

Comment: Thank youuuu! I was about to throw all my hardwork away and there was just this simple problem